# Convert Range of Numbers to Square Feet

Tags: php

I am using this function which works fine for a single number entered by user in format `1000` and `1,100`

```
function metersToSquareFeet($meters, $echo = true)
{
    $m = $meters;
    $valInFeet = $m*10.7639;
    $valFeet = (int)$valInFeet;
    if($echo == true)
    {
        echo $valFeet;
    } else {
        return $valFeet;
    }
}
```

I need to modify for the case where users enter a range of numbers in the format: `1000-2000`

The function should be smart enough to convert both numbers and in this case output in this format `10,763-21,527`

Comment: okay, so what have you tried?

Comment: appears to be a "do my work for me" post, rather than a "here is where I'm stuck" or "what am I doing wrong?" question.

Comment: i ve been playing around with stripping the numbers individually based on the '-' but i am getting parsing errors. my php sucks!

Comment: use `explode()` with hyphen as delimiter to get each number as an array element, and then do calculations for each element in the array

Comment: you can `explode` by hyphen regardless if it's passed `12345` or `123-456` and always do calculations on the first element `$array[0]`. Then check if there's a 2nd array element `$array[1]` and if so, do calculations on that too

Comment: excellent ! had no idea..

Comment: Why change the function? Why should a function that does square meters to square feet conversion do anything other than that? If you are trying to do this because you get input in this range format, then keep the string splitting logic outside this function. The function should do one thing and one thing only. If this means you need another function to accept the input you want and then call this function a couple times the do that.  It is genrally a better design approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to parse the input yourself.

If you enter in 1000-2000 as a parameter it will think that it's -1000 as it will do the math.

- I'm suggesting you change your input to either 2 parameters, an array or a string.
- If using a string, use substring to find the int position of '-' https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php or use explode like @crayonviolet suggested
- Convert both numbers by your constant (10.7639)
- Return your desired output as a string or as part of an array

Your choice depends on how your convertToSquareFeet function is used in other parts of your application and the code rework it would have by changing the parameter list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using string already and will use the explode() function as suggested by Crayon - thanks for the guidelines